# Unable to retrieve data for a specific date in SQL

Tags: sql, date

I'm trying to retrieve data for a specific date with query:

```
Select * from table_1 where activity_date = to_date('13-09-2017','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

But I'm not getting any result.

But when I query below:

```
Select * from table_1 where activity_date >= to_date('13-09-2017','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

I'm getting the data for days greater than equal to 13-09-2017.
Any help?

Comment: Could you include a few rows of data from your table, especially rows with a activity_date value of 13-09-2017?

Comment: Is activity_date datetime? I agree with @MartinJoiner that some data would help.

Comment: Below are few rows from table: `13-SEP-17 37643654 1100 input_data Functional Error. An event already exists
13-SEP-17 39763654 1100 input_data Application: Error in Process`

Answer (score 1):

When you compare dates remember that **you usually compare some kind of a timestamp**. A **timestamp usually also has hours, minutes, seconds** etc. So in your database you probably have a whole timestamp like '13-09-2017' + specific hour, minutes and so on, whilst to_date explicitly only formats your DD MM and YYYY causing the hour, minutes and seconds to be equal to 0. The query is probably not returning any records as you probably don't have a date with the exact time equal to 00:00:00.

That's also why a comparison like >= will return results. Because your '13-09-2017' database entries are all greater than '13-09-2017' (with hour equal to 00:00:00) because they all have some hours, minutes and seconds to them, for e.g `13-09-2017 04:02:45` which is greater than `13-09-2017 00:00:00`).

**How to solve this?** Well for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 
WHERE activity_date >= to_date('13-09-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') 
  AND activity_date < to_date('14-09-2017','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the data type of your column is Date Time and hence when you are querying with just date (13-09-2017), it searching for date as well as time (13-09-2017 00:00:00). Seems there are no record in your database with this exact date time stamp and hence no results are being returned. Below query will work in your case:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE activity_date >= to_date('13-09-2017','DD-MM-YYYY')
  AND activity_date < to_date('14-09-2017','DD-MM-YYYY');
```